chmod: cannot access '/opt/firefox/firefox': Not a directory
I am using this Dockerfile via docker-compose
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONBUFFERED=1 \
    GECKODRIVER_VER=v0.34.0 \
    FIREFOX_VER=120.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    gcc libc-dev libpq-dev  python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python3-lxml curl unzip xvfb wget openssl bzip2 firefox-esr

# Add FireFox
RUN set -x \
   && apt install -y \
       libx11-xcb1 \
       libdbus-glib-1-2

ADD distr/firefox-120.0.tar.bz2 /distr/firefox
RUN mv /distr/firefox /opt/ \           <--- ERROR ON THIS STEP
   && chmod 755 /opt/firefox \
   && chmod 755 /opt/firefox/firefox
  
# Add geckodriver
ADD distr/geckodriver-v0.34.0-linux64.tar.gz /distr/geckodriver
RUN mv /distr/geckodriver/geckodriver /usr/bin/ \
    && chmod 755 /usr/bin/geckodriver

WORKDIR /project
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .


The build is working fine on my PC, but in gitlab-CI I have an error:

chmod: cannot access '/opt/firefox/firefox': Not a directory
The command '/bin/sh -c mv /distr/firefox /opt/    && chmod 755 /opt/firefox    && chmod 755 /opt/firefox/firefox' returned a non-zero code: 1

Build script in .gitlab-ci.yml
.build_template: &build
  stage: build
  variables:
    DOCKER_BUILD_OPTS: ''
    DOCKER_BUILD_CONTEXT: './project'
  script:
    - docker login -u ${HARBOR_USERNAME} -p ${HARBOR_PASSWORD} ${HARBOR_HOST} 2>&1
    - docker build ${DOCKER_BUILD_OPTS} -t ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} $DOCKER_BUILD_CONTEXT 2>&1
    - docker push ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} 2>&1
    - if [ ! -z ${CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS} ]; then export CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME; fi
    - if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "dev" ] || [ "$FORCE_BUILD" == "dev" ]; then
        export IMAGE_TAG=dev;
        echo -e "Image tag add:\ ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}" 2>&1;
        docker tag ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} 2>&1;
        docker push ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} 2>&1;
      fi
    - if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "main" ] || [ "$FORCE_BUILD" == "latest" ]; then
        export IMAGE_TAG=latest;
        echo -e "Image tag add:\ ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}" 2>&1;
        docker tag ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} 2>&1;
        docker push ${HARBOR_HOST}/${HARBOR_PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} 2>&1;
      fi
  tags:
    - linux-shell


How to fix the error in gitlab-CI environment?
UPDATE
Added debug steps:
Step 6/16 : RUN ls -la /distr/firefox
 ---> Running in 6f7276d058ba
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 133 Jul 31 16:25 /distr/firefox
Removing intermediate container 6f7276d058ba
 ---> d4832dbd102f
Step 7/16 : RUN ls -la /opt/firefox
 ---> Running in 4197c83dbdcd
ls: cannot access '/opt/firefox': No such file or directory



You could insert a RUN ls -la /opt/firefox statement after the RUN mv and before && chmod ... to confirm the folder structure.

@DazWilkin. I have this output: Step 7/16 : RUN ls -la /opt/firefox  ---> Running in 4197c83dbdcd ls: cannot access '/opt/firefox': No such file or directory

The distr/firefox-120.0.tar.bz2 file in your build context does not appear to be a bzip compressed tar file. So docker is coping the file rather than extracting it into the directory. After the mv command runs, there is an /opt/firefox but it's a file, and not a directory containing the extracted /opt/firefox/firefox. The fix is to correct your source of the distr/firefox-120.0.tar.bz2 file.

Thank you, but distr/firefox-120.0.tar.bz2 looks fine. How should I change the it?

Your debugging shows that it's a 133 byte file. How did you create it and what do you expect it to contain?

Attached example of the Firefox archive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uUTME5_15gUo7hnKvBf4gzD4CyDZl91x/view?usp=sharing

Add to your debugging the command cat /distr/firefox to view the contents of the file.
